# play audio file in lightning component

Tags: static-resources

I have added an mp3 file as a static resource, can someone please help me to call that resource in the lightning component so when I hit the button it will play that static resource 
as per the Salesforce documentation I have tried below but instead of playing the sound it is displaying the message.

[image]

Comment: ui:message is a TTS service, not for playing arbitrary audio files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use audio tag and specify source of music file in order to play music in Lightning components. For example :

```
<aura:component>
    <audio src="https://chiraglex-dev-ed--c.ap4.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P6F00002CXedP" 
            autoplay="true">
    </audio>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in javascript when a button is pressed.

```
 var playSound = new Audio(urlAudio);
    playSound.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Play using static resource. Upload a music file to the static resource, copy the link of the file and use in the following fucntion and call it where you want to play the sound.

```js
beep(){

    var beepsound = new Audio(Static Resource URL);   
    beepsound.play();   
    console.log('beep ');

};
```